# Image Recognition (Shape recognition)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I want to recognize the shapes in the picture by template matching.Is the "ExhaustiveTemplateMatching" is the right option given in Aforge.Net for this purpose.Had anyone tried this class and find it working correctly.How accurate and right choice this class is for achieving my purpose.Suggest any other methods or Alogrithms as well for recognizing shapes by matching template.For example Identifying ComboBox in a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV's MatchTemplate works pretty well especially after you have run an edge detection (like Canny) on source and template. You  might also want to look into SURF (Speeded up Robust Features).